# DIV de subqueries falhando: Every derived table must have its own alias

Tags: mysql

Numa tabela, possuo dois campos: entry_time e exit_time. Quero fazer a subtração de cada registro (exit - entry) pra achar a espera de cada cliente, somar todas as esperas, e tirar uma média dessa soma pelo número de clientes.

Existem algumas condições que já estão na query mas em essência o que quero é:

```
sum(exit_time - entry_time) div count(*)
```

Possuo uma query que me trás uma exibição nos dois campos gerados que preciso fazer o DIV():

```
SELECT SUM(espera) soma, COUNT(*) as totalregistros FROM 
   (SELECT timestampdiff(minute,queue_entry_time,queue_exit_time) espera 
       FROM queue_element where status='done') soma;

        +------+----------------+
        | soma | totalregistros |
        +------+----------------+
        |   45 |              8 |
        +------+----------------+
```

Se tento dividir um campo pelo outro recebo o seguinte erro:

```
SELECT soma div totalregistros from (
   SELECT SUM(espera) soma, COUNT(*) as totalregistros 
      FROM (SELECT timestampdiff(minute,queue_entry_time,queue_exit_time) espera 
         FROM queue_element where status='done') soma);

ERROR 1248 (42000): Every derived table must have its own alias
```

Porém não consigo ver qual subselect está sem alias. Vale lembrar que não posso utilizar procedures ou tabela temporária no meu cenário.

Alguém poderia apontar meu erro? Obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu erro esta que falta declarar um as XXX no fim

```
SELECT soma div totalregistros from (
   SELECT SUM(espera) soma, COUNT(*) as totalregistros 
      FROM (SELECT timestampdiff(minute,queue_entry_time,queue_exit_time) espera 
         FROM queue_element where status='done') soma) as Resultado;
```

Mas pra simplificar ja tentaste assim ?

```
SELECT (SUM(espera) div COUNT(*)) as resultado FROM 
   (SELECT timestampdiff(minute,queue_entry_time,queue_exit_time) espera 
       FROM queue_element where status='done') as reFinal;
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! Funcionou perfeitamente!